# How to get input name on button of the same <tr> clicked with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have multiple `input` in the same `<table>`. Then I want to get its `name` on the same line `x` button clicked. But every time it returns undefined. I knew that it's must be something wrong about pointing to the input's name. Here's my code:

```js
$('.delno').on('click',function(){
    var pname=$(this).parent('tr').find('.price').attr('name');
    console.log(pname);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <tr>
    <td class="align-middle text-center">1</td>
    <td class="w-10 p_2hi"><input type="number" class="form-control price" onfocus="this.select();" onmouseup="return false;" name="f4eaca5b2376160b9b6c8d542a89ba88" value="1" /></td>
    <td class="align-middle text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger delno">x</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="align-middle text-center">2</td>
    <td class="w-10 p_2hi"><input type="number" class="form-control price" onfocus="this.select();" onmouseup="return false;" name="fa0410ac57ba1a277da3e37c6cc30606" value="1" /></td>
    <td class="align-middle text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger delno">x</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="align-middle text-center">3</td>
    <td class="w-10 p_2hi"><input type="number" class="form-control price" onfocus="this.select();" onmouseup="return false;" name="853ce96cd36d3d6b6cb5aa179ea930bb" value="1" /></td>
    <td class="align-middle text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger delno">x</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In this case I understand that. I have to find the  input class `.price`. Then get its `name` attribute. Inside the top level `<tr>`. But it seems wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue**

`.parent()` only travels a single level up the DOM tree

https://api.jquery.com/parent/

**Solution**

Use `.parents()` or `.closest()`

https://api.jquery.com/parents/

https://api.jquery.com/closest/

```js
$('.delno').on('click', function() {
  var pname = $(this).closest('tr').find('.price').attr('name');
  console.log(pname);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <tr>
    <td class="align-middle text-center">1</td>
    <td class="w-10 p_2hi"><input type="number" class="form-control price" onfocus="this.select();" onmouseup="return false;" name="f4eaca5b2376160b9b6c8d542a89ba88" value="1" /></td>
    <td class="align-middle text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger delno">x</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="align-middle text-center">2</td>
    <td class="w-10 p_2hi"><input type="number" class="form-control price" onfocus="this.select();" onmouseup="return false;" name="fa0410ac57ba1a277da3e37c6cc30606" value="1" /></td>
    <td class="align-middle text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger delno">x</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="align-middle text-center">3</td>
    <td class="w-10 p_2hi"><input type="number" class="form-control price" onfocus="this.select();" onmouseup="return false;" name="853ce96cd36d3d6b6cb5aa179ea930bb" value="1" /></td>
    <td class="align-middle text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger delno">x</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```